# How do I disable hint arrows in Splatoon 2?

Tags: splatoon-2

Sometimes in *Splatoon 2*'s single player campaign when the game thinks I'm taking too long to progress it will play a pinging noise with flashing arrows telling me where I need to go (This is easily demonstrated with the Grapplinks in level 6).

Is there a way to disable these flashing hint arrows?

Comment: I have no idea if you can disable them, but I don't think this is necessarily because it thinks you're "taking too long to progress". I'm pretty sure I still get those arrows even when running through the levels quickly. The main purpose of the single player's early levels is to teach you how to play the game, after all, so that's basically acting as the tutorial, no matter how quickly you're getting through them.

Comment: I don't believe they can be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The hint arrows don't appear when you're taking too long. They appear when you get an item or unlock something. Take, for example, getting a key. When you get the key, it will automatically start flashing the arrow in the direction of the vault that key goes to. There is no way to disable them. You just need to get to the objective as fast as possible. As for the Grapplinks, there are always arrows flashing like that for level 6. Level 6 is a pretty challenging level, what with the Octozeppelins, and it is sometimes hard to find where you're going. They just put those in to help you with a challenging level.